# Rotation of figure around axis x=2 versus around x=0.

Tags: integration

I have two equations $y=2x  $  and $y=x^2$ which are revolved around x=2.

My integral is $2\pi \int_0^2 (2-x)(2x-x^2) $.

In another question, I have  $y=2x  $  and $y=x^2$ which are revolved around x=0. This integral is
$2\pi \int_0^2 (x)(2x-x^2) $

The first and second volume turn out to be equal. This is not intuitively clear to me. I would expect different volumes, since shells of different areas are making different rotations in the first and second problem.

Any help?

Comment: You can also use Pappus's Theorem to see why this is true, since $V=A(2\pi\rho)$ where $\rho$ is the distance from the centroid of the region to the axis of revolution, and the centroid of this region lies on $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating by oatmeal boxes like this, $V=\int2\pi rh\,dr$, if we add the same function of $x$ to both the upper and lower curves, then $h(x)=(y_2(x)-f(x))-(y_1(x)-f(x))=y_2(x)-y_1(x)$ hence also the volume, doesn't change.

Thus we choose to add $f(x)=-2x$ to both curves to get $y_2(x)-f(x)=2x-2x=0$ and $y_1(x)-f(x)=x^2-2x=(x-1)^2-1$. Now the symmetry of both upper and lower curves about $x=1$ is evident, so it should be clear that rotating about two different axes positioned symmetrically about $x=1$ should yield the same volume, $\frac{8\pi}3$.